# Show entries in the Control Panel as a grid, to reorder position

Tags: entries, control-panel, order

I am looking for a way to display entries in a (5er) grid
in the Craft backend (Control Panel) and show only the featured images.

I have a customer who has on her website a gallery, where 5 squares are on
one row. Right now there are around 50 entries, more to come.

All the squares are entries, which have detailed information
on a certain product behind it. The squares are pictures and the customer wants to be able to reorder them, to get the best (aesthetic) combination.

I was thinking of a structure because with this it is easy to order
the entries, but in the Control Panel they are shown as a list.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I was thinking maybe the Neo plugin might be of help, but I could not try it.

Answer (score 1):

In the Craft backend, I don't think this is possible without (creating) a plugin or module of sorts. Even then, I don't think the element index page is extendable enough to accomplish what you want to accomplish.

Even if you were able to get this done, one way or another, how would you take into account a responsive situation, where more or less than 5 image squares are shown for larger or smaller screens? Would the CP mimic this behaviour?

The only thing I can think of is some sort of table field ([Super Table](https://plugins.craftcms.com/super-table), maybe?), in which you have 5 columns and any number of rows, and every column contains one asset field.